# LaunchImage via Asset Catalog breaks layout on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode7

I'm using Xcode 7.0 with an Enterprise Developer Certificate.

The App I'm developing uses seperate Storyboards for iPhone and iPad.
The Layout uses Table Views.

[image: Layout]

Whenever I'm setting the Launch Image Source via the Asset Catalog i noticed that on some devices (specifically iPhone 6, 6 Plus, 6s and 6s Plus) the layout behaves strangely. 
The content frame is being resized.

On all other devices in the Simulator it appears as intended.

**This is the misbehaving layout:** 
[image: layout misbehaving]

When I set the Launch Image Source to "don't use asset catalogs" it also appears as intended.

**This is the layout as intended:** 
[image: Layout as intended]

Unfortunately I only have iPhone 5s and iPad Mini 2 for testing, so I do not know if this also happens on real >iPhone6 devices.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

In the Interface builder I selected my Table View, then Size Inspector, then selected all Autoresizing options.

[image]

Now everything works as intended again.